# add the parent DOM nodes class in to the its child dom

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the parent DOM nodes class in to the its child dom ,

For example lets say ,

```
<ol class="test1">
        <li>
        <li>
           <ol>
```

I want to say to to the child ol to get all the classes which is in its parent ol .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').attr('class', function() {
    return $(this).closest('ol').attr('class');
});
```

or without jQuery:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=lis.length; i--;) {
    lis[i].className = lis[i].parentNode.className;
}
```

The LI tags will of course have to be closed for this to work

Comment: @ArunPJohny - didn't notice! changed my mind and added a js solution

Comment: thanks guys,

 but if there are several classes and if they are dynamically added by a user , say push of a button or some thing how do i alter this ?

Comment: The code above will add any and all classes that the parent OL has to the children LI.

Comment: HI adeneo , but what I want to do is to put the parent ol class to child ol so if I say it like this 
$('ol').attr('class', function() {
    return $(this).closest('ol').attr('class');
})

is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test1").find('ol').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("class",$(".test1").attr('class'));
    });
});
```